# How do I place a static wallpaper in that theme?

Tags: html, css, tumblr

The html is here
http://static.tumblr.com/taepiis/5SFln832d/theme.txt

It's a simple thing, but I'm quite confused here. where and what's the script to place a wallpaper there?

Answer (score 1):

If by wallpaper you mean the background, find this line:

```
background: #fafafa url('http://static.tumblr.com/taepiis/vDkln0pwq/2560_16v00.jpg') fixed repeat-x 0 0;
```

Change the URL in the `url('...')` part.

Comment: i'm sorry, i meant this one http://static.tumblr.com/taepiis/Nsmln83to/theme2.txt